# How can I represent a function that maps to a set of intervals?

Tags: functions, interval-arithmetic

Usually, we formally represent a function by specifying the sets that are related by the function.

For example, let us consider the following function:

$i \colon \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

It maps two real numbers in another real number.

But, how can I formally represent a function that maps, for example, two real numbers n1 and n2 to the interval [n1,n2]?

It is not clear to me how to do that. On of my intuitions was recognizing that an interval is just a set of real numbers (considering the example). So, it would be possible to represent the function in the following way:

$i \colon \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to 2^{\mathbb{R}}$

Considering that $2^{\mathbb{R}}$ is the powerset of $\mathbb{R}$, that is, the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

But this does not capture the whole information that I would like to express. For example, it does not capture the notion of beginning and end of the interval. So, I think that I can use additional information. For example, in this spirit, I think that I can define the above function in the following way:

$i \colon \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to 2^{\mathbb{R}}$ such that, $i(x,y) = [x,y]$.

Does this make sense?

PS: Please, consider this function just as an example. I'm not interested in this particular function.

Comment: You probably don't want to use $2^\mathbb{R}$. While there is a very easy (definable) correspondence between $2^\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal P(\mathbb{R})$ the first is really a set of $\mathbb{R}$ length sequences of 0's and 1's. Otherwise you are fine in the way you define your function. I would choose the right hand side smaller though since it gives the wrong impression. $\mathcal P(\mathbb{R})$ is much, much larger than the set of intervals.

Comment: I'm nota familiar with this notation. It os not just another notation for the notion of powerset?

Comment: @zaratura I'm not sure what you mean saying you're not familiar with "this" notation. Which is "this" notation. $2^\mathbb{R}$ is not the powerset of $\mathbb{R}$. We just sometimes call it that, but it's abuse of notation.

Comment: Hi. I was not familiar with $\mathcal P(\mathbb{R})$. Does it mean "the powerset of \mathbb{R}"? And what does it mean $2^\mathbb{R}$?

But, considering that we consider $\mathcal P(\mathbb{R})$ as the powerset of $\mathbb{R}$, my above reasoning is correct?

Comment: $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is the usual notation for $\{B;B\subset A\}$ (i.e. the power set of $A$). $2^{A}$ is the usual notation for $\{f;f:A\rightarrow 2 \wedge \text{$f$ is a function}\}$ it happens to be the case that $2^{A}$ has the same cardinality as $\mathcal{P}(A)$ and the correspondence is particularly trivial.

Comment: Your reasoning is fine but it would probably seem a bit strange. As I said above the power set of $\mathbb{R}$ is much larger than the set of intervals of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that. But I don't know how to constraint more the definition of my function.

And thank you for your explanation.